# How can documents held in cloud storage be safeguarded against malware?

Tags: malware, cloud-storage

The place where I work stores company documents in the cloud. I just want to know whether malware can still access and conduct their malicious activity against these cloud-based documents ?

Staff access these document either via a browser-base word processor or via the cloud storage client app - so my guess is that the malware on the staff PC could access these cloud based documents and wreak havoc just as easily as if these documents were held on the local PC storage.

Are there any safeguards that can be put in place ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can access these documents, and some malware even searches them out.

The protections are the same as if you were not using remote storage: backups, journaling file systems, version control.

Your specific cloud provider might have additional tools, but that will be up to the individual vendors.